# How to get './manage.py syncdb' to create additional views or run custom SQL?

Tags: django, django-models, django-syncdb

Is there a way to run some custom SQL statements after syncdb does it thing creating the tables for the models? Specifically, I would like to create some database views.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note: As mentioned in the comments, this method is deprecated as of Django 1.7.

Or just create a file called sql/<modelname>.sql:
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/#providing-initial-sql-data

Comment: This works nicely enough, but the entire "custom SQL" feature has been termed a "hack" by one of the core developers, and a preference was expressed for using the post_syncdb signal.  Can't find link at the moment.  In any case it's guaranteed to stick around until 2.0, so no worries.

Comment: This does not work. Running `manage.py sqlcustom <myapp>` ignores all my sql/<modelname>.sql files.

Comment: Hmm. I haven't tried this in quite a while, but the latest docs still indicate this should work. The files should be called  <appname>/sql/<modelname>.sql

Comment: Deprecated officially as of Django 1.7 https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/initial-data/#providing-initial-sql-data

Answer (score 9):

Yes, there are signals you can catch after a syncdb.

See [management signals](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#management-signals) for docs.

This is how the contrib.auth permissions table is populated, as well as the contenttypes framework table.